# How to use tabs as horizontal indentation and spaces as vertical indentation in Vim?

Tags: vim, alignment, indentation, auto-indent

Is there a way to configure Vim so it combines tabs to use as horizontal indentation character, and spaces as vertical indentation character (for instance, when continuing long lines, giving out arguments to methods)? Basically, something like this (i have marked tabs with > and spaces with dot):

```
class xyz {
>   function abc()
>   {
>   >   $var1 = "this is a multi-"
>   >   ......+ "line string which spans "
>   >   ......+ "several lines";
>   }
}
```

Ideas or suggestions?

Edit: I'm not looking how to use spaces instead of tabs, I'd like to *combine* them in a way I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ["Smart Tabs" script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=231) that may be what you're looking for. It describes itself as using tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment.

Comment: I know it's the least descriptive thing one can say, but *it doesn't work*... Do you have any idea what would be the proper way to use it? I'm editing PHP files, and it won't do anything more than VIM does on its own.

Comment: @mr.b I am able to see a difference if I change $var in your example to $really_long_var, so that the alignment needed is more than a tab width. In that case vim by default uses a combination of tabs and spaces, the plugin uses only spaces.

It seems like this isn't a complete solution, though, since it needs to be taught the alignment rules (e.g. line up with the = sign in your example), and could probably use a custom binding on <Tab> to use spaces where appropriate in cases not covered by the alignment rules.

Comment: I'll award you bounty points, as you did set me on the right track to a solution. I've contacted plugin author, and he says that plugin is basically responsible for indendation AFTER non-space char. So if I were to have, say, several assignments to variables say $short_var $bit_longer_var and $very_very_long_var, I could indent = signs to be one above the other, and the space between variable names and = signs would be filled by spaces only, and not by tabs+spaces. Vim options are solely responsible for what I asked, so I'll go dive into docs to find a correct set of options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines to $HOME/.vimrc

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

This should set a tab to 4 spaces.
Here is the VIM Wiki on this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces

Comment: Thank you.. But, I'm sorry, I guess I wasn't as concise as I should have been when asking my question. Please read my edit above...

Comment: Oppa, I just didn't read your comment well enough. Apologizes. As for the actual question, I do not know of a way. Hopefully someone else will be able to provide an answer.